# rephrasing of don't have to

Tags: sentence-meaning, paraphrasing

*There doesn’t have to be an answer to every question.*

I think this sentence can be rephrased as below.

*It is not necessary that there (should) be an answer to every question.*

1. Can the first sentence also be rephrased as below?

*It is possible for every question not to have an answer.*

2. Can the first sentence also be rephrased as below?

*There may not be an answer to every question.*
(=*It is possible that there is not an answer to every question.*)

Comment: A little math logic here for operator *not*, rather than English. "It is possible for **every question** not to have an answer" seems to focus on every question having no answer. That statement is overly broad. You mean *not* every question has an answer, not that all have no answer.

Comment: O.K. I think you mean the answer of the first question is "no". Then, how do you think about the answer of the second question?

Comment: It is not necessary that there etc. is simply not used that much.

Comment: “doesn't/don't have to” can almost always be replaced by “need not”.